# Material Angular 6 DatePicker is parsing my date 1 day before

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

There's something really weird happening to the current version of the Material Angular DatePicker, after I updated it from A5 to A6 it started to parse my date 1 day before, the example is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-datepicker-parsing-wrong-date

I'm using the original documentation example with a slight change on the language to my own language, and applying a custom date value to the ngModel so it can parse.

But you can check the code here:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-locale-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-locale-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-locale-example.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'pt'}, //my change from the original documentation example
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerLocaleExample {
  constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<any>) {}

  private someDate = '2018-01-31'; //my change from the original documentation example

  french() {
    this.adapter.setLocale('fr');
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatePicker" placeholder="Different locale" [(ngModel)]="someDate"> <!-- my change from the original documentation example -->
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #myDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-hint>Actual Date: {{someDate}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-button (click)="french()">Dynamically switch to French</button>
```

Does anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: are you in a negative offset timezone ?

Comment: I'm at UTC+1 / UTC+2 here and I don't have any trouble, so I guess it's related to a local display of date, timezine related. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FPfn.png

Comment: @Pac0 I'm in -3h, I had my code wrong, please update your screen and tell me if it's ok.

Comment: Here is what I see when I start the application : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDwDv.png
.
Nothing changes when I click "switch to French".

If I change the date, then I have.this (message changed)  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIjwT.png . And clicking on the switch button doesn't change anything either.

However, no problem with the date (on my side)

Comment: Tested the stackblitz as well, no issue on my side.

Comment: @Pac0 and penleychan so we can agree is a locale issue, right? Now, how to solve this?

Comment: @ErickXavier could you give screenshots (and/or do some output in console and copy it into your question) of the exact problem you are facing ?  As of now, I am not sure to really understand whate you are experiencing

Comment: I would call that mainly a *timezone* and client-dependent display problem, which involves locale, but I don't think the timezone is part of what programs mean by "locale"

Comment: Yes guys, this is a timezone issue. To fix it, badly, I had to concatenate T00:00:00 in my string, but I'm working with the backend guys to see if we can change the column type at the database to accept *yyyy/MM/ddTHH:mm:ss* instead of only *yyyy/MM/dd*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, after a little bit of research I've find out that it was a timezone issue. To temporary fix it, I had to concatenate *T00:00:00* to the end of my date that was coming from backend under the format *yyyy/MM/dd*.

The best option is, if it's possible, to the backend to change the format to *yyyy/MM/ddTHH:mm:ss*.

Otherwise there's 2 options to solve the problem when you have to use the format *yyyy/MM/dd* in your Angular 6 Material DatePicker: te bad and the good.

- The bad (and possible just a temporary) is to do what I did, concatenate *T00:00:00* to the end of the date before the DatePicker parses it.
- The good is to actually get the date string, convert it into date, convert the timezone to GMT and then allow the DatePicker to parse it.

I hope I can help the desperate all over, like me.

Comment: In my case I was Using java.time.LocalDate in the backend istead of java.time.LocalDateTime.
Change the type of Date and problem solved

Comment: Can you please share the code

Comment: @AdnanFayaz sorry, i dont have it anymore. It's been 5y sincee I worked on this.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who just wants their dates to be UTC dates and is stuck using the JS Date object via DatePicker, you can just add an adapter option to the `@NgModule` providers:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDatepickerModule, MatMomentDateModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }
  ]
})
```

You'll need add `@angular/material-moment-adapter` to your `package.json` and import the module/options object:

```
import {MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, MatMomentDateModule} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
```

Once this is done, any DatePicker will provide UTC dates, and considering there's no opportunity to select a time component with DatePicker, this seems appropriate.

Pulled from the [Material DatePicker info](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.md#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings).

Answer (score 5):

You can do a parse function, like this:

```
let newDate= new Date(oldDate);
newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + newDate.getTimezoneOffset());

return newDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';

formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en');
```

Comment: Does this solve the issue that the OP is having? Why?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34403950)